# How to manage NSUserDefaults when switching between different tabs in tab bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsuserdefaults

In my iPhone app, I have the unique identifier for eah project. I want that when the user logs in the unique identifier be accessible on every page.

I am using NSUserDefaults to do that. But the problem is that Login is not the first page. So if I access some page which requires unique id, then it shows "unknownkey".

How can I work around this problem?

Also, I can't add the login screen as first screen as the user can access some portions without login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"uniqueid"]) {
   //...user is not logged in..
} else {
  //...user is logged in...
}
```

Comment: But first time if user hasnt logged in and if the user is on a page where there is no definition of "uniqueid" . Then it gives error:  valuefor<undefinedkey> and crashes out.

Comment: objectForKey returns nil if the key is not set, see: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Another solution would be to store another unique identifier to the NSUserDefaults before the user is logged in, treating the user as unauthorized whenever this special identifier comes up

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is a design problem rather than a programming problem?

You could probably either move your login screen to the startup screen or leave the tab bar as it is until the user logs in, or even re-design the whole thing differently.

Comment: I have editeed my question. so please check the `Edit` portion.

Comment: My answer doesn't change really. You have to rework your design.

Answer (score 0):

If the login is necessary for everything (e.g. your app is a dropbox client), present the login viewController modally at application start.
And don't dismiss it until you have a successful login.

Answer (score 0):

In your RootViewController's viewDidLoad method, you need to check the saved NSUserDefault via an IF statement. Easy.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:@"uniqueid"]) {
    // here you'll want to present a view modally inside a new navigation controller. 

    LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

} else {

    // this is where you'd set up the client if the user is already logged in.

    }
 }
```